# Button activating when area outside of button is clicked (Java/Blackberry App)

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have been working on an application for blackberry, which orginally had two buttons (`btn1` and `btn2`) on the screen. Now I've added a third and i am experiencing some difficulties (`btn3`).

Originally `btn1` and `btn2` were side by side, and clicking outside the button, but below it would activate the button ... a design flaw but could be overlooked.

However, I need to add a button below `btn1` and when i did that two weird things occured: First is that, even if i click `btn3` which is BELOW `btn1`, focus shifts to `btn1` and `btn1` is called.  And clicking `btn2` shifts focus to `btn3` and it is activated.

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening but i'm playing around with the code pasted below. Any little help is appreciated.

```
    btn1 = new CustomButtonField("", Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button-disabled_1a.png"), Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button-normal_2.png"));      
    btn2 = new CustomButtonField("", Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button-disabled_3.png"), Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button-normal_4.png"));
    btn3 = new CustomButtonField("", Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button-disabled5.png"), Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button-normal_6.png"));

    Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("background.png"));

    HorizontalFieldManager vfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(){
        public int getPreferredHeight() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Display.getHeight();
        }

        public int getPreferredWidth() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Display.getWidth();
        }

        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int count = getFieldCount();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++ ){
                Field f = getField(i);

             if(f == btn1 ){
                 setPositionChild(f, (getPreferredWidth() >> 1) - f.getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight()>>1);
                    layoutChild(f, getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
                }else if (f == btn2 ){
                    setPositionChild(f, (getPreferredWidth() >> 1) +30, getPreferredHeight()>>1);
                    layoutChild(f, getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
                }else if (f == lblName ){
                    setPositionChild(f, 30, getPreferredHeight()>>1 - btnLicense.getPreferredHeight());
                    layoutChild(f, ( getPreferredWidth() * 3 ) >> 2, getPreferredHeight());
                }else if (f == btn3 ){

                    setPositionChild(f, (getPreferredWidth() >> 1) - f.getPreferredWidth() -0 ,  getPreferredHeight()- getPreferredHeight()+280);
                    layoutChild(f, getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
                }

            }
            setExtent(getPreferredWidth(),getPreferredHeight());
        }

        public void subpaint(Graphics graphics){
            int count = getFieldCount();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++ ){
                net.rim.device.api.ui.Field f = getField(i);
                paintChild(graphics,f);
            }
        }

    };
```

Custom Button Field

```
package com.app.ui.component;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;

public class CustomButtonField extends Field {

    /** To set background image for button field */
    private Bitmap bkImage;

    /** To set Focus image for button field */
    private Bitmap bkFocusImage;

    /** int value for Field Width */
    private int fieldWidth;

    /** int value for Field Height */
    private int fieldHeight;

    /** Text to write on Button */
    private String text;

    /** Text Color on Button */
    private int textColor = Color.WHITE;

    /** Default Font for Button */
    private Font defaultFont = Font.getDefault();

    /**
     * Constructor with
     * @param text
     * @param image
     * @param focusImage
     */
    public CustomButtonField (String text, Bitmap image, Bitmap focusImage) {   
        this(text, image, focusImage, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor with
     * @param text
     * @param image
     * @param focusImage
     * @param style
     */
    public CustomButtonField(String text, Bitmap image, Bitmap focusImage, long style) {
        super(Field.FOCUSABLE | style);
        this.text = text;
        bkImage = image;
        this.bkFocusImage = focusImage;
        fieldHeight = bkImage.getHeight();
        fieldWidth = bkImage.getWidth();
    }

    /**
     * To get the exact width needed by the field borderWidth - used to show the
     * width of focused rectangle around the button
     */
    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return fieldWidth;
    }

    /**
     * To get the exact width needed by the field borderHeight - used to show
     * the height of focused rectangle around the button
     */
    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return fieldHeight;
    }

    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
    }

    /**
     * To set the background according to focused state of the field
     */
    protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean flag) {
        graphics.setFont(defaultFont);
        if (bkFocusImage != null) {
            graphics.drawBitmap((getPreferredWidth() - bkFocusImage.getWidth()) / 2,(getPreferredHeight() - bkFocusImage.getHeight()) / 2,
                    bkFocusImage.getWidth(), bkFocusImage.getHeight(),bkFocusImage, 0, 0);
        }
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        int textWidth = defaultFont.getAdvance(text);
        graphics.drawText(text, (fieldWidth - textWidth) / 2,(fieldHeight - defaultFont.getHeight()) / 2);
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setFont(defaultFont);
        if (bkImage != null) {
            graphics.drawBitmap((getPreferredWidth() - bkImage.getWidth()) / 2,(getPreferredHeight() - bkImage.getHeight()) / 2,
                    bkImage.getWidth(), bkImage.getHeight(), bkImage, 0, 0);
        } 
        graphics.setColor(textColor);
        int color = (isEnabled())?Color.BLACK:Color.DARKGRAY;
        graphics.setColor(color);

        int textWidth = defaultFont.getAdvance(text);
        graphics.drawText(text, (fieldWidth - textWidth) / 2,(fieldHeight - defaultFont.getHeight()) / 2);
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        fieldChangeNotify(0);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: please show the code where you create your buttons and other fields.

Comment: i added the code to create the button in an edit

Comment: but, we still don't know what `CustomButtonField` is.  that's not a standard BlackBerry class.  so, we would need to see the constructor for that class, as well as what it inherits from.

Comment: added it to the orginal code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty easy problem to have when you're first implementing custom BlackBerry buttons and fields.  First of all, the problem here is that your `CustomButtonField` class, which is a button field written from scratch, is not properly determining which touch events (or navigation events) are *within its extent* (inside the field's area).

One way to fix this is to modify your `navigationClick()` method, and implement the `touchEvent()` method:

```
   protected boolean touchEvent( TouchEvent message )    {
      int x = message.getX( 1 );        
      int y = message.getY( 1 );        
      if( x < 0 || y < 0 || x > getExtent().width || y > getExtent().height ) {
         // Outside the field            
         return false;       
      }        

      switch( message.getEvent() ) {                  
      case TouchEvent.UNCLICK:                
         fieldChangeNotify(0);               
         return true;        
      }        
      return super.touchEvent( message );    
   }

   protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
      if (status != 0) {        // you did not have this check
         fieldChangeNotify(0);
      }
      return true;
   }
```

Another option, that I would actually recommend, is to replace your entire `CustomButtonField` class with one of the samples from BlackBerry's [Advanced UI library](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java)

You can use the [BitmapButtonField](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/component/BitmapButtonField.java), and the [BaseButtonField](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/component/BaseButtonField.java) that it extends, to achieve the same functionality, with proper touch / click handling.

While you're there, take a look at some of the other UI classes in that library, as you'll probably find them quite useful.

Comment: I tried the 1st options but not much has changed...Everythig works fine when i use the touches on the keyboard. But the touches on the screen still the same. Doesnt work right.

Comment: @kemnet, did you put the code above in your `CustomButtonField` class? if it doesn't work, you've done something wrong. i will also say, again, that you should completely replace your `CustomButtonField` code with the blackberry advancedUI `BitmapButtonField` class.